# SQL (oracle) imposing hierarchy on where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Table Name: REG_NBRS

```
STATE        CITY      COUNTRY   REG_NBR
------------------------------------------
ILLINOIS               USA       444333222
NEBRASKA               USA       111222333
             NEW YORK  USA       333444555
FLORIDA                USA       666222666
             TAMPA     USA       888333888
```

I have data something like this and I need to get REG_NBR for that state or city. If the row matches both for state and City, city takes precidence, and if it is not matched for either state or city, then I will have to still list the row with null for reg_nbr.
I tried to come up with a query but didn't get much successs as I don't know how to impose a precidence while doing an outer join.

```
SELECT C.NAME, C.AGE, RN.REG_NBR
  FROM CUSTOMER C, REG_NBRS RN
 WHERE C.COUNTRY = RN.COUNTRY
   AND (C.STATE = RN.STATE OR C.CITY = RN.CITY)
   AND C.ID BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

As a beginner, I do not know how to join these two tables in such a way that

1. it joins first on STATE and City
2. But still list all 1000 rows
3. Put null to those registered numbers which are not from those states or cities
4. If both match, then use the State's Registered number (i.e. use 666222666 for Tampa even though we can find an entry for TAMPA)

I am sorry if this is not making sense but I have tried to explain as much as possible. I have also tried different combinations of left outer join and right outer join but couldn't get how to impose a hierarchy for WHERE coinditions. I thought of UNIONS but I think even unions would list 2 rows for a customer in Tampa with both REG_NBRs. 
Any suggestions?

APOLOGIZE for jumbled code as I am using a (not so) smart phone to post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have unique keys in (Country, State) and (Country, City), you can do it in a simple way by joining twice:

```
SELECT 
  C.NAME, C.AGE,
  COALESCE(RN1.REG_NBR, RN2.REG_NBR) AS REG_NBR
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT OUTER JOIN REG_NBRS RN1
  ON RN1.COUNTRY = RN1.COUNTRY
 AND RN1.STATE = C.STATE
LEFT OUTER JOIN REG_NBRS RN2
  ON RN2.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY 
 AND RN2.CITY = C.CITY 
WHERE C.ID BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

Moreover this should be faster than the OR, which databases don't like much (at least with proper indexing in place).

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you for your response.. I didn't know about Coalesce before... Changed my complex query  to ANSI standards and used your trick.. Thanks.